# Value not getting inserted in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I've made this small little code to track my daily expenses and earnings from various sources.
Anyway, the first query increments the record id + adds the time.
But, the second query doesn't seems to be doing anything.
Any ideas? Here's the code :-

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
include('dbconnector.php');
if(isset($_REQUEST['action']))
{
    switch($_REQUEST['action'])
    {
        case 'inpute':
        $amt=(isset($_POST['amt'])) ? $_POST['amt'] : '';
        $desc=(isset($_POST['desc'])) ? $_POST['desc'] : '';
        if(!empty($amt) && !empty($desc))
        {
            $query = 'insert into tb1(record_id,record_date) values (NULL,now())';
            $result = mysql_query($query, $db);
            $query2='insert into input(record_input_id,amt_in,in_desc) values (NULL,"' . $amt . '", "' . $desc . '"';
            $result2=mysql_query($query2, $db);
            if($result && $result2)
            {
                header('Location: index.php');
            }
            else
            {
                echo "Error";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo "value cannot be null";
            header('Refresh:3;URL = index.php');
        }
        break;
        case 'outpute':
        $amt=(isset($_POST['amt'])) ? $_POST['amt'] : '';
        $desc=(isset($_POST['desc'])) ? $_POST['desc'] : '';
        if(!empty($amt) && !empty($desc))
        {
            $query = 'insert into tb1(record_id,record_date) values (NULL,now())';
            $result = mysql_query($query, $db);
            $query2='insert into output(record_output_id,amt_out,out_desc) values(NULL,$amt, "' . $desc . '"';
            $result2=mysql_query($query, $db);
            if($result && $result2)
            {
                header('Location: index.php');
            }
            else
            {
                echo "Error";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo "value cannot be null";
            header('Refresh:3;URL = index.php');
        }
        break;
        default:
        header('Location: index.php');
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: you have million of insert queries , just post your problem code.

Comment: seems like you forgot ")" in the end of the query?

Comment: @Victor it still prints "Error".

Comment: Use `mysql_error()` instead of "Error", everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You're posting the same query twice!

Use following insert statements: (I've included Victor's answer - thanks!)

```
$query = 'insert into tb1(record_id,record_date) values (NULL,now())';
$result = mysql_query($query, $db);
$query2='insert into output(record_output_id,amt_out,out_desc) values(NULL,$amt, "' . $desc . '")';
$result2=mysql_query($query2, $db);
```

For `$result2` you originally executed `$query` as well, but that was already inserted...

And **PLEASE** consider using prepared statements... As well as mysqli_*-functions or PDO.

> [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a few (potential) issues with your code.

Firstly, you miss the closing bracket `)` on `$query2` - both times.

Secondly, you need to place `$amt` in quotation marks when referencing in the query. Otherwise when it is empty (i.e. `$amt == ''`) the query will fail.

Third, you reference `$query` in two `mysql_query` calls in the second `case`.

Fourth, while not an issue per-se, I'm assuming that all of the `record_id` and `record_*_id` fields are set to auto increment? If this is the case you can omit them from the query entirely (as opposed to setting them to `NULL`)

Your queries should end up looking something like:

```
$query2="insert into input(amt_in, in_desc) values ('$amt', '$desc')";

$query2="insert into output(amt_out,out_desc) values('$amt', '$desc')";
```

---

### More info

If the above doesn't work try inserting the following after your problem `mysql_query` calls:

```
echo $query, "<br>"; //Use $query or $query2 depending on what one you called!
echo mysql_error(), "<br>";
```

This will show you any errors that were thrown and also the used SQL statement which can help massively when debugging!

For example, in your queries when `$amt` is empty your query will look something like:

```
insert into output(record_output_id,amt_out,out_desc) values(NULL,, "descending"
```

Which won't work (as stated *secondly* earlier) see the two commas with no value - where `$amt` should be?